# How to align text in Bootstrap grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 column grid in Twitter Bootstrap.  Each cell has text.  For one column, I'd like to right align text and adjust right side padding for those cells.  Is there something built into Bootstrap for this?

Or do I need to write a class and attach it to each cell that needs this alignment?

Comment: `.text-right` and padding will have to be done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap class is `text-right`.

For the padding, you'll have to manually add any overrides to your CSS somehow. Either a consistent container for your third column. Or add a wrapper  with a class to increase the padding on the right. (Though extraneous divs are never good!).

Just in case: I don't recommend adding this additional padding to override `text-right` itself since that may have weird effects elsewhere in the site when you use this same class.

Source: [http://www.getbootstrap.com/css/](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)